# create object with records from obj1 of columns also included in obj2

Tags: r

I have an object `obj1` containing columns `A, B, C, D, xx, yy` . Another object `obj2` contains columns `B` and `C`. I want to retrieve all columns which are present in both `obj1` and `obj2` and stock them in obj3.

Doing this name by name works:

```
col_names <- names(obj2) % this returns strings "B", "C"

for(i in 1:length(col_names)){  
    matching_col <- obj1[, match(x = col_names[i], names(obj1))]
}
```

Is there a way of doing this without the for loop, something like:

```
matching_cols <- obj1[, match(x = names(obj2), names(obj1))]
```

The result would be something like:

```
obj3 <- obj1[, matching_cols]
```

Comment: `intersect(names(obj1), names(obj2))`

Comment: @RonakShah Should be an answer.

Comment: sweet! intersect() works just fine. @RonakShah, if you answer the question I'll accept it

Comment: Regarding the possible duplicate, my question is slightly different as I actually want to create another object obj3 with the values in obj1 but only the columns present in obj2. I'll modify the text to make it clear.

Comment: @akrun: I modified the text of the question. I don't believe it is still a duplicate

Comment: @akrun no problem, and thanks for pointing to the other post.

Comment: @Nic Have a great day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `intersect` to get the common names from two dataframes

```
intersect(names(obj1), names(obj2))
```

Now to select these common columns into a new dataframe `obj3` we can do

```
obj3 <- obj1[, intersect(names(obj1), names(obj2))]
```

Comment: can you please modify the answer as to adapt it after my latest modification?: obj3 <- obj1[, intersect(names(obj1), names(obj2))]